# Deserializing JsonArray

Tags: c#, json, json.net, face-api

I've written a code which calls an API which returns a Json Array which I have tired to deserialize using Json.net as below-

```
static async void MakeAnalysisRequest(string imageFilePath)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        // Request headers.
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", subscriptionKey);

        // Request parameters. A third optional parameter is "details".
        string requestParameters = "returnFaceId=true";

        // Assemble the URI for the REST API Call.
        string uri = uriBase + "?" + requestParameters;

        HttpResponseMessage response;

        // Request body. Posts a locally stored JPEG image.
        byte[] byteData = GetImageAsByteArray(imageFilePath);

        using (ByteArrayContent content = new ByteArrayContent(byteData))
        {
            // This example uses content type "application/octet-stream".
            // The other content types you can use are "application/json" and "multipart/form-data".
            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

            // Execute the REST API call.
            response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);

            // Get the JSON response.
            string contentString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            // Display the JSON response.
            Console.WriteLine("\nResponse:\n");
            List<Facejson> obj=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Facejson>>(contentString);
            Console.WriteLine(obj[0].Face.faceId);
        }
    }

 public class Facejson
{
    [JsonProperty("face")]
    public Face Face { get; set; }
}

public class Face
{
    [JsonProperty("faceId")]
    public string faceId { get; set; }
}
```

The Api response Json is in the format

```
  [
   {
  "faceId": "f7eda569-4603-44b4-8add-cd73c6dec644",
  "faceRectangle": {
     "top": 131,
     "left": 177,
     "width": 162,
     "height": 162
    }
  },
  {
  "faceId": "f7eda569-4603-44b4-8add-cd73c6dec644",
  "faceRectangle": {
     "top": 131,
     "left": 177,
     "width": 162,
     "height": 162
    }
  } 
]
```

When I compile my code, the following error shows up

> Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

in the line

```
Console.WriteLine(obj[0].Face.faceId);
```

I have declared the method "Face" but it shows that I have not. What am I doing wrong?

Edit- fixed Json and faulty code fixed as suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are deserializing a `List<Face>`, so to access one item on this list, you will have to use an index:

```
Console.WriteLine( obj[0].Face.faceId );
```

Or enumerate all results one-by-one:

```
foreach ( var face in obj )
{
   Console.WriteLine( face.Face.faceId );
}
```

### Update

You are deserializing a wrong type. Your JSON is directly a list of `Face` class instances, so the `FaceJson` type is not necessary:

```
List<Face> obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Face>>(contentString);

foreach ( var face in obj )
{
   Console.WriteLine( face.faceId );
}
```

Comment: I have made the change that you suggested but I now am getting a Null reference exception. I'm sure these values exist in the json. I even printed the json just to confirm.

Comment: Run the program in debugger and see if the `obj` variable is not null and if it contains some instances of your `FaceJson` class

Comment: I have updated my answer with fixed code, the problem was in the JSON formatting.

Answer (score 1):

JSON string you shared is not correct. Please check this [fiddle](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=edc81211a0d7ad05e15d72c4d79b9d02).

```
[
  {
    "faceId": "f7eda569-4603-44b4-8add-cd73c6dec644",
    "faceRectangle": {
      "top": 131,
      "left": 177,
      "width": 162,
      "height": 162
    }
  },
  {
    "faceId": "f7eda569-4603-44b4-8add-cd73c6dec644",
    "faceRectangle": {
      "top": 131,
      "left": 177,
      "width": 162,
      "height": 162
    }
  }
]
```

Also you are deserializing a `List<Face>` , you can access it using index only.

**UPDATE**

You need to deserialize `List<Face>` not single `Face` class. It will solve you problem.